# Не получается импортировать .pyd в python

Tags: python, ctypes

```
import ctypes
lib = ctypes.PyDLL('hidapi.pyd')
```

Выдает ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "h:/blade_pro_hainEdition/test.py", line 2, in <module>
    lib = ctypes.PyDLL('hidapi.pyd')
  File "C:\Users\Hainter(10)\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 356, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 193] %1 не является приложением Win32
```